# Compile C programme into standalone DLL using mingw

Tags: c

Im wondering whether it's possible to generate a standalone DLL from a simple C programme.

I have the following code to create a user and add to admin group on successful execution.

I can compile this into a executable using:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o useradd.exe useradd.c
```

Which when execute works, but wondering whether this can be turned into a standalone DLL using mingw32 compiler?

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* system, NULL, EXIT_FAILURE */
/* Creates a user called sharepoint with password sharepoint. Add's user to local administrators group. */
int main () {
int i;
i=system ("net user sharepoint sharepoint /add & net localgroup administrators sharepoint /add"); return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just change the extension of the generated file to .dll only difference between .dll and .exe in Windows is one is executed and the other isn't.

Comment: That is actually not the case in this instance. I have tried that.

Comment: You need to export a function from DLL which perform the functionality written in your current main function. For how to create a DLL using mingw [refer here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampledll)